# How do I copy a table from one SQL database to another?

Tags: database, sql, postgresql

I have a database (it's Postgres, if that matters) and I would like to take two of its tables, export them, and then import them into another database. How do I do that?

Edited to add Google bait: dump load

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use pg_dump with the -t option (which you can specify multiple times):

```
pg_dump -t foo -t foo1 dbname1 > dump.sql
```

Restore in the new database:

```
psql -U username dbname2 < dump.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

If the other database is not managed by Postgresql use pg_dump, as in Gary's hint, but with the -D flag, it makes the import process much more robust. You will have to create the schemas on the target system

(sorry, can't add a comment to Gary's answer as I don't have enough points)